# How to make keyboard: false in bootstrap modal window?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

this is  my code

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="test1.php" data-target="#myModal">click me 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="test2.php" data-target="#myModal">click me 2</a></li>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    $(this).removeData('modal');
});
</script>
```

here how i disable "backdrop" and "keyboard" from model window

i try some thing like below

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  keyboard: false
})
```

but not working wel

Answer (score 0):

delete this line

```
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
```

i traced the event, found something triggered this button .

Answer (score 0):

Here's an HTML solution:

```
<a href="#" data-controls-modal="your_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

"""

Comment: please describe in detail